# 4-d double array can't be saved into .mat matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, save, 4d

I have 4-D double array named pic, with dim of ( 512, 512, 100, 29). 
actually they are '.nii' images with dim of ( 512,512,100) . 
each .nii image has 100 slice.
I loaded 29 nii image in matlab in pic(:,:,:,i) array and now I want to save it.
but matlab does not save it correctly.

```
save( 'mypic.mat' ,'pic');
```

matlab shows warning :

```
Warning: Variable 'pic' cannot be saved to a MAT-file whose version is 
older than 7.3. To save this variable, use the -v7.3 switch. Skipping...
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is too large to save using the default .mat file format, as the warning *clearly* states, you need to use the `-v7.3` switch to save this size of file

```
save('mypic.mat', 'pic', '-v7.3')
```

See [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html) for more information on the various .mat file formats and their benefits and drawbacks.